# Terms Of service And Policy on Azure AD B2C Android

Tags: android, azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

can we able to add ,i agree to `Terms of Service` and `Privacy Policy` regarding the privacy of our  `App`  on Azure AD B2C page loaded on our Android APP?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this sample to add TOS:
https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/terms-of-service

Answer (score 0):

Using custom policy you can add Terms of service with a checkbox in the Sign Up and Sign In page.

You can use a sample like [this](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/sign-in-sign-up-versioned-tou) which presents a checkbox, and writes the version of the Terms of service that was presented.

Using the Custom HTML you can customize the way of showing the TOU. Please refer the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/customize-ui-overview) for Customizing the UI

Comment: can we show it as a link on signup page and on tapping that link, user will be able to see the `privacy policy`. how can that be done?

Comment: yes you put the hyperlink in the custom HTML file. Use some JavaScript within your custom HTML to move it to the correct position.

Comment: what will be best way to show Azure AD B2C SigninSignUp on mobile app? Is it better we have a extra page before loading the webview or is it ok if we directly show the webview after splash screen?

Comment: I think its okay to show the webview after the splash screen but finally it needs to be your call to choose the right one.

Comment: Thats great.  Are we able to provide our own apps privacy policy on signup page ??

Comment: It would be the same process (custom HTML)

Comment: @ Nishant - Need to implement a custom Policy in-order to have it integrated. I got the idea, regarding it, need try once the Custom Policy is Done